# Dunn test in R: error message about something being coerced to a factor

Tags: r, statistics, kruskal-wallis, dunn.test

I am trying to conduct a Dunn test in R. This is my code:
`DTP = dunnTest(P~SoilSeries, data=df3, method="bh")`
I get this error message: `Warning message: SoilSeries was coerced to a factor.`
I don't know what to do. I turned SoilSeries into a factor with as.factor but then df3 was no longer a table. I'm a beginner and am very confused, so would really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `SoilSeries` is a column in `df3`.
And I assume `df3` is a `dataframe`, if not you can first convert `df3` to df,

```r
df3 <- as.data.frame(df3)
```

Then use the `as.factor`

```r
df3$SoilSeries <- as.factor(df3$SoilSeries)
```

And `Warning message: SoilSeries was coerced to a factor.` is not an error, R simply converted SoilSeries to factor for the Dunn Test.